# Remove Excel Hyperlink Screen Tips

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-2016, vba

When you add a hyperlink in Excel it creates a screen tip which you can modify it by going to edit hyperlink and the "screentip" but how would I remove it completely so that when you put your courser over a hyperlink that nothing appears.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperlink objects have a [ScreenTip property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197693.aspx) which is read/write.

If you set this property to the empty string, however, you will end up with a lengthy default ScreenTip that describes how to follow the link and how to edit the cell. The closest you can get to having no ScreenTip is to set the property to a single space - this makes the ScreenTip appear as a small box with no text:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).ScreenTip = " "
```

[image: Part of an Excel spreadsheet with a hyperlink in cell A1. The hyperlink text reads "A hyperlink" and there is a small white box immediately below the text]

There doesn't seem to be any obvious way to eliminate the ScreenTip entirely

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to ask an obvious question, but have you selected Remove Hyperlink?

Comment: Wouldn't that remove the Hyperlink, and not just the associated ScreenTip?